# Post/Edit/Delete Post From Frontend... How?

Tags: posts, front-end

I've been given the challenge (challenge for me anyhow) of creating a way for website users to post/edit/delete posts based on their user name.

I'd actually prefer to code something like this myself rather than using a plugin for this.. Although if there are some plugins which could partially help me achieve a good result, I'd be really happy to.

Anyhow, I couldn't actually find anything which would help me achieve this, the best thing I found was Gravity Forms along with another plugin which would give me a result I'm not exactly sure of.

So, my question is, as someone who hasn't done anything like this before in WordPress, what would be the best way to do something like this and where do I start?

Comment: To get started, you may want to review the following functions: [wp_insert_post](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_post), [wp_update_post](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_update_post), [wp_delete_post](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_delete_post), and [get_post](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post)

Comment: @czerspalace thanks for your help! :) ..it looks fairly straight forward to achieve, we'll see how I go